# Ruby code check: Does my code make sense/is it the best way to do what I'm doing?

Tags: ruby, github, syntax

I'm sort of in between that phase of newbie/intermediate when it comes to programming Ruby, and I know the way to become more of an expert is to practice.

I thought I would make a more complex program to split a meal check evenly between 4 people.

I have an array `courseTotals` set for when we get a total cost for each course of the meal we use `.insert(whatever variable)` to insert that total into the array.

There's also a lot of nested `if/else/elsif` statements and a few `case` statements for when we need to calculate for more than 1 item for each course.

**NOTE: THIS PROGRAM ISN'T FULLY COMPLETED!**

I'm simply wanting to check, with people who have more experience than me with Ruby, if I'm using best practices and to get potential feedback.

I appreciate any input that is given. You're sincerely thanked from an aspiring programmer

[Git Repository](https://github.com/BigDaddyDeadpoo1/mealForFour-Incomplete-)

Comment: This is better suited to the [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) site.

Answer (score 0):

The logic of the case and if/else statements makes sense. The syntax of your insert method calls is incorrect, it should be like this `courseTotals.insert(indexToInsertAt, objectsToInsert)`. You might consider using `courseTotals.push(objectToAddToArray)` instead of insert to append values to the end of the array. Also, if you send the inputs your program receives to downcase you won't have to worry about whether the user input is upper or lowercase. When looking for y/n input, you should probably handle "n" input explicitly with its own elsif rather than letting else handle it. If you wanted to allow the program to accept variations of yes and no as input, instead of comparing the input with == you could use the match method. Example: `appetizers.downcase.match(/\Ay/)` will return nil unless the first character of string appetizers is a "y".

Comment: Is it  `.downcase.match(/\Ay/)`? Or does the `A` specify the first character of the string inputted by the user?

Comment: @BigDaddyDeadpoo1, So the \A is a special character in regular expressions known as an anchor, and it essential says only match the pattern if it occurs at the beginning of the string. So for example, .downcase.match(/\Ay/) will match any string whose first character is the letter y. More info here: [link](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Regexp.html#top)